# Create then populate colmuns in a dataframe

Tags: r

Hello I'm trying to find a way to create new columns in a dataframe the populate them.

For example:

```
id = c(2, 3, 5) 
v1 = c(2, 1, 7) 
v2 = c(1, 9, 5) 
duration=c(v1+v2)
df = data.frame(id,v1,v2,duration,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  id v1 v2 duration
1  2  2  1        3
2  3  1  9       10
3  5  7  5       12
```

Now I want to create new columns by dividing each value of  a row by the 'duration' of said row, I know how do it manually but it is prone to errors and not really elegant...

```
df$I_v1=v1/duration
df$I_v2=v2/duration
```

Or is `df <- df %>% mutate(I_v1 = v1/duration)` quicker/better?

```
  id v1 v2 duration      I_v1      I_v2
1  2  2  1        3 0.6666667 0.3333333
2  3  1  9       10 0.1000000 0.9000000
```

It works but I would like to know if it's possible to create -and name- the row and populate them automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that you have a `cols` vector containing the names of the columns you want to manipulate. In your example:

```
cols<-c("v1","v2")
```

Then you can try:

```
df[paste0("I_",cols)]<-df[cols]/df$duration
#  id v1 v2 duration      I_v1      I_v2
#1  2  2  1        3 0.6666667 0.3333333
#2  3  1  9       10 0.1000000 0.9000000
#3  5  7  5       12 0.5833333 0.4166667
```

Comment: Perfect. I didn't know about paste0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform()`:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(2, 3, 5), v1=c(2, 1, 7), v2=c(1, 9, 5))
df$duration <- df$v1 + df$v2) # or ... <- with(df, v1 + v2)

df_new <- transform(df, I_v1=v1/duration, I_v2=v2/duration )
```

... or (if you have many columns v1, v2, ...):

```
as.matrix(df[, 2:3])/df$duration # or with cbind():
cbind(df, as.matrix(df[, 2:3])/df$duration)
```

(similar as in the answer from *nicola*)

Answer (score -1):

All data frames have a row names attribute, a character vector of length the number of rows with no duplicates nor missing values. You can name the rows as:

```
row.names(x) <- value
```

**Arguments:**

x
object of class "data.frame", or any other class for which a method has been defined.

value
an object to be coerced to character unless an integer vector.e here

Comment: How this answers the question?